# Is 2 valued logic "The one true logic"?

Tags: logic, soft-question, philosophy

Nonstandard logics are included in the formal content of 2-valued logic as "object theories", and can be embedded in the formal structure of 2VL as special-purpose "subtheories". 2VL can in principle be taken as content by its subtheories, but this is a bit deceptive, as the subtheories still rely on 2VL for intelligibility (that's why they're the "subtheories", and 2VL is the "theory" or "metatheory" - only 2VL has what it takes to define identities and qualify on its own as an intelligible theory which renders its content identifiable). So really, it's more like 2VL taking itself as content through its subtheories. That being understood, nonstandard logics can be very useful for describing uncertainty, indeterminacy, potentials, possibilities, probabilities, quantum wave functions, the metaverse, and so on - one just has to be careful about what one is doing, and how one is doing it.

What do you make of this? Is it correct to say this?

Comment: I think it is hard to say. I'm personally drawn towards intuitionistic logic, which emerges quite naturally as the internal logic of a topos. From the perspective of type theory, classical logic isn't necessarily so appealing. Definitely not to anyone who takes a constructivist perspective. Whenever I'm doing any work in automated theorem proving I always feel kind of dirty invoking the law of the excluded middle over predicates I haven't shown to be decidable. I feel like if we're working towards a "one true logic", the model of HoTT may be as appealing if not more than classical approaches.

Comment: @Jack: If nothing else, I feel that it would suggest there is no "one true logic", and that Platonism should be uprooted from mathematical discourse.

Comment: [Suszko showed](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-values/suszko-thesis.html) every structural Tarskian logic is characterised by a class of $2$-valued models. Malinowski noted such models aren't necessrily structural, but proved a similar result: every structural $q$-logic is characterised by a class of $2$-valued $q$-models, or a class of $3$-valued $q$-models.

Comment: It is hard to argument that there is "only one True logic". For sure, classical two-valued logic is very "natural" and has the stronger support for mathematics and human experience. Maybe somday we will discover that some basic hardware or firmware of human mind is 2-valued...

Comment: @Asaf Crazy talk...

Comment: @Andrés: "Don't you know I'm loco?", to quote a certain Hill of Cypresses... :)

Comment: I'm afraid your question is far too unclear to be answerable even as a matter of opinion. However, I think it is clear that the real world obeys classical logic; all (successful) branches of science are based on that. This does not imply that human reasoning/language obeys classical logic; after all many humans are irrational...